# Jquery Datatables passing extra parameters while making Ajax call

Tags: datatables

I am using Jquery Datatables to populate some data from the server. Below is the code I am using.

```
          var table = $(function  ()  {
           var table=$('#dataTable').dataTable( {
              "jQueryUI": true,
              "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
              "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
              "sAjaxSource": HOST_NAME+"/states/",
              "sAjaxDataProp": "content",
              "bFilter": true,
              "oSearch": {"bRegex":true, "bSmart": false},
           });
           var tt = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools( table );
         });
```

But during the ajax call I see an extra parameter `http://myserver.com/states?_=1410160127424`. I do not want to send the `__=1410160127424` parameter since I am using varnish to cache the data. How to override the default implementation to restrict the extra parameter in the url.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery dataTables are using jQuery AJAX. So simply change the default settings for AJAX sessions :

```js
$.ajaxSetup({ 
   cache: false 
});
```

Comment: @Pradeep, just realized - what version of dataTables are you using? To answer your question, this should be runned __before__ any `dataTable()` but if you use 1.9.x or below, another approach is nessecary (in 1.9.x cache is hardcoded inside the datatables script)